# How to bind column header to property in ViewModel? (WPF MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datacontext

I Have window that have DataContext that is bind to ViewModel object (VM1 for the example).
VM1 have a lot of properties and one of them is a string that called "MyTitle".

I have a DataGridTextColumn in  'Window\Grid\DataGrid'. How can I bind the property "Header" in DataGridTextColumn to the Property "MyTitle" in my VM1 ViewModel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately, the column definitions of the `DataGrid` don't inherit the `DataContext`, because they're not part of the visual tree, so you can't bind directly to the ViewModel. You need to resort to a workaround such as the one described in [this article](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/):

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>

...

<DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Data.MyTitle, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
```

Comment: give this man a medal! thankyou so much for this! it works great!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use a binding proxy, like too often suggested.
Obviously, `DataGridColumn.Header` is not a `DependencyProperty`. To still bind it, simply define the `Header` explicitly using XAML property element syntax, and bind the header content:

```xml
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.TextValue}" />
      </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

I was able to make this work.

```
<FrameworkElement x:Name="proxy" DataContext="{Binding}"/>

<DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Source={x:Reference proxy}, Path=DataContext.MyTitle}/>
```