# WPF datagrid header not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following `datagrid`:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="control" HeadersVisibility="Column">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="{Binding DataContext.Localization.Id, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="{Binding DataContext.Localization.Name, ElementName=control}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

In my `ViewModel` I have a localization object which contains all the strings of the ui loaded from the resx:

```
public class ClientListLocalization : LocalizationBase
{
    private string _id;
    private string _name;

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    internal override void Localize()
    {
        Id = Resources.clientview_id;
        Name = Resources.clientview_name;
    }
}
```

And my view model (simplified)

```
public class ClientListViewModel
{
    public new ClientListLocalization Localization { get; set; }
}
```

But in my application, headers are not updated, both with the first way (using `RelativeSource`) or the second way (using `ElementName`)

Any clues ?

Comment: What is Localization here in DataContext.Localization.Id?

Comment: @Vijay: an instance of ClientListLocalization contained in the view model used as datacontext. ViewModel is actually ClientListViewModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution fixed my problem: [How to bind column header to property in ViewModel? (WPF MVVM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965615/how-to-bind-column-header-to-property-in-viewmodel-wpf-mvvm)

The column definitions of the `DataGrid` don't inherit the `DataContext`, because they're not part of the visual tree, so you can't bind directly to the `ViewModel`.