# Adding Header Style to DataGrid overrides (hides) data using Binding on header

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, styles

I need to Style the WPF dataGrid headers AND bind the header data.

Binding works OK using:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.HeadData, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
```

If I now add a header style to the DataGrid, the TextBlock in the style overrides the binding data.

I'm using all the latest Dot-Net and VS 2019.

Any idea how to marry the two requirements? It's consumed me!

Rich

Comment: If I understood correctly, you should be able to do this: `<DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding DataContext.HeadData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}" />`. The TextBlock should not be needed, since Header converts it automatically. I also think that in this scenario, all the RelativeSource stuff would not be needed, since you should still have the same DataContext as the DataGrid one.

Comment: Header="{Binding HeadData}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}">   Shows the style colours etc but no text from binding.    

Neither does the boring Ancestor version.

The only way I can get bound data is using:
   <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.HeadDay, RelativeSource=               {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />  
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>

However, if I add style it overrides the bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've tried it myself and this is the solution I've found:

You have to define the `TextBlock` inside the Style definition

```xml
<Style x:Key="MyHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.HeadData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In some way, setting an Header Style, and specifying an Header content gives conflict.
So you have to move everything inside the style.

Obviously you use the Style just like this.

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn HeaderStyle="{StaticResource MyHeaderStyle}" />
```

Hope I've been helpful.

### EDIT

This solution doesn't works (or else, it works for one column only `DataGrid`).
In the comments I linked a solution given on a different question, that could be used here as well.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. The only issue I see is that it works nicely for a one- column dataGrid,  but I have a dozen columns. I would need a style for each column. Not a huge problem but typically with XAML very lumpy. Unless I'm probably missing something..

Comment: Do you have N properties that must be bound to N DataGridColumns' Header? I would go with AttachedProperties, if you need an example I can extend my answer with one.

Comment: Attached properties sounds like it could solve other 'lumpy' issues for me. Yes Please.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't able to make it works. Luckily I was able to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965615/how-to-bind-column-header-to-property-in-viewmodel-wpf-mvvm) solution, that worked in my tests. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Federico, Looks good I'll work on it soon. In the meantime your other solution is working for me.  I think it should be the answer.